# WCF Diagnostics tracing and WAS hosting?

Tags: wcf, trace, was

I have a WAS hosted set of services configured to use net.tcp running under an IIS AppPool user account. When hosting the services with WAS I have a hard time getting any diagnostic tracing out of them to track down problems. The same services with tracing set to use i.e. c:\logs\trace.svclog as trace output works fine when using self-hosting in a console application.

I don't seem to get any trace output at all when hosting with WAS, are there any special settings I need to get trace output under WAS? I have set a fixed output path for tracing and assigned permissions to the folder for the IIS AppPool\MyAppPool-user.

/Per Salmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that something was suddenly broken in my .NET Framework 4.0 installation, all works well after a repair installation of the framework.

/Per